# Occasional freezes

Tags: freeze, lenovo-desktop-computer

My main computer is a Lenovo M92p with Intel i7 3770, 16gb of ram and intel hd graphics 4000.

Every once in a while my computer just freezes completely, and shuts off after about a minute.  All I can do is wait for it to shut off or shut it off manually with the power button; nothing else works.

There doesn't seem to be a rule for it, it just happens randomly, it can happen once a day or once a week.  What I have noticed is that whenever it happens, I have to let the computer "rest" for a while, otherwise it usually freezes after a short amount of time again.

It doesn't matter what operating system I am using, or how much times I keep formatting my system; it keeps happening.  Right now I am using Ubuntu 14.04, but it also happens with Windows.

It seems that the problem might have something to do with temperature of some components, but everything seems to be cooled properly, the computer never heats too much and always stays quiet.

The problem has been occurring for a very long time.  I posted a thread in the Lenovo forums, but no one was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

As you state, it seems to be overheating.

[Lenovo claims](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops/thinkcentre/m-series-towers/m92p-sff/) its "Intelligent Cooling Engine (ICE) 2 is designed to provide a balance between thermals and acoustics resulting in long desktop life. With two optimized settings, you choose the performance mode that best suits your work environment, prioritizing temperature or sound. Plus, ICE 2 allows for working in hotter temperatures and enables system monitoring with thermal alerts that preempt overheating possibilities."

1. Verify that nothing blocks airflow, e.g. a soft pad underneath or object next to the computer that might block vents.
2. Try the more aggressive cooling setting. See the [m92p user manual, p 114](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/463490/Lenovo-Thinkcentre-M92p.html?page=114) for directions.
3. Clean heat-sinks and fan. Just dust or vacuum; it should not need application of thermal compound.
4. Check that heat sinks are correctly attached, and that nothing is blocking air flow.
5. At least temporarily, try adding another fan externally. If that resolves the issue, you could install one, whether externally or internally, permanently.

Comment: I did clean the front fan last month because it was very dusty.
I will try your other suggestions.
It is hard to determine whether the issue is resolved or not, because it is not something that i can trigger, i just happens randomly, once a day, once a week and sometimes even once a month.